# How to avoid multiple mutable borrows

Tags: rust

I am currently stuck in a situation wherein it seems impossible to avoid having multiple mutable borrows. This is my code

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct A {
    a: i32
}

impl A {
    fn fun1(&mut self, i: i32) {
        println!("fun1: {}, {}", i, self.a);
    }
    
    fn fun2(&mut self, i: i32) {
        println!("fun2: {}, {}", i, self.a);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a_obj = A {
        a: 9
    };
    
    let mut l: HashMap<String, Box<dyn FnMut(i32)>> = HashMap::new();
    l.insert(String::from("abc"), Box::new(|param| a_obj.fun1(param)));
    l.insert(String::from("def"), Box::new(|param| a_obj.fun2(param)));
    
    let key1 = String::from("abc");
    let h1 = l.get_mut(&key1).unwrap();
    h1(3);
    
    let key2 = String::from("def");
    let h2 = l.get_mut(&key2).unwrap();
    h2(686);
}
```

Error

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `a_obj` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:24:44
   |
23 |     l.insert(String::from("abc"), Box::new(|param| a_obj.fun1(param)));
   |                                            ------- ----- first borrow occurs due to use of `a_obj` in closure
   |                                            |
   |                                            first mutable borrow occurs here
24 |     l.insert(String::from("def"), Box::new(|param| a_obj.fun2(param)));
   |                                            ^^^^^^^ ----- second borrow occurs due to use of `a_obj` in closure
   |                                            |
   |                                            second mutable borrow occurs here
...
27 |     let h1 = l.get_mut(&key1).unwrap();
   |              ---------------- first borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

Comment: Why does it seem impossible? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you are borrowing twice `a_obj` as mutable, it's not legal rust.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the error message is bugus/misleading since it's show param and not `a_obj`. I have read enough rust question to know people don't really read compiler message :p

Comment: @Stargateur I think it points at the closure, pointing only at the parameters and `||` to be short.

Comment: It indeed seems impossible. Now, what do you _really_ want? Because this artificial code may require `RefCell`, but your real code may not.

Comment: An obvious modification to this code is not to store the mutable reference into the closures, but to pass it when calling them: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ab21c9a49074b41ae023a2073bf7254).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman let's say I have requirement of receiving multiple messages(with unique message identifier) from some source. Based on message identifier I want to call a method which further processes that message. In my case the first parameter is always `&mut A`, so I want to fix that and only put placeholder for the second parameter. just like C++ `std::bind`. https://godbolt.org/z/xE5doY9er